# VALUES(?) как работает в Sqlite3/Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, select, sqlite3

Не могу разобраться как использовать переменные в запросах к БД Sqlite3 в Python3.
Можно ли использовать конструкции с VALUES(?) после FROM (когда имя таблицы берется из переменной), и после WHERE (когда в условиях сравниваются переменные со значениями столбцов).
В INSERT INTO - работает, просто вставляет значения столбцов.
А в данном простом запросе выборки с условием никак. Не хочется верить, что это не реализовано.

ПРИМЕР:

```
table1 = "days"
yr="2022"
d="1"
m="1"

cur.execute("""SELECT ym1, ym2 FROM (VALUES(?)) WHERE (year = VALUES(?)) AND (month = VALUES(?)) AND (day = VALUES(?));""", (table1, yr, d, m))
```

Ошибка:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "VALUES": syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
table1 = "days"
yr="2022"
d="1"
m="1"

cur.execute(
  f"SELECT ym1, ym2 FROM {table1} WHERE year = ? AND month = ? AND day = ?;", 
  (table1, yr, d, m)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Про таблицу не в курсе, подозреваю что нельзя. Но что вообще делает слово `values` во всех этих местах? Это ж не update.

> ```
> WHERE (year = VALUES(?)) AND (month = VALUES(?)) AND (day = VALUES(?))
> ```

```
WHERE year = ? AND month = ? AND day = ?
```

Comment: Необходимость есть, т.к. нужно выбрать данные и вставить/заменить их в текстовых файлах с переменными-шаблонами. Есть несколько таблиц в БД, несколько вложенных циклов. Писать сотни однотипных SELECT-ов не хочется.
Если, действительно невозможно, то думаю формировать динамически строки с уже статическим SQL-запросом. И его выполнять. Типа cur.execute(static_sql).

Comment: После FROM ни ?, ни (?), ни VALUES(?) - не работает подстановка.
А вот после WHERE year = ? - работает. 
Ну хоть так пока.

Comment: @НиколайВасонов, ну я как-то так и ожидал.